# Understanding My Logins

Tags: support, login, openid

In the past, I logged into SO using the Google account method. However once the StackExchange OpenID was available I switched to using this, but used my gmail address to create the StackExchange account.

On the My Logins page, it seems to show that when I login using the StackExchange method, I'm also logged in to Google too.

[image: My Logins]

It doesn't seem to set a Google cookie, so is this just a quirk from having a previous Google login with the same email address? Am I correct in thinking no data is shared with Google when I login? Is it safe to remove the Google login method now?

Comment: Eh, SE login is awfully complicated. OpenID has since been replaced with a standard email login feature (the one you're seeing on the list there). The My Logins GUI is confusing though. Having used Google once, it weirdly linked that email as an email login method too. I removed the google login, but could still log in with Google. Google only gets info if you use it to log in directly, but not if you use the email directly (there's no two-way data sync). That being said, I removed the Google login before the OpenID option was removed - things might've changed since then.